# Remove title of application in toolbar

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

How do I go about removing the title of my application in the top toolbar of my application or make it run in the background where the finder will be the active application but mine will still run?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to run your app in background without a dock icon simply set `LSUIElement` to `YES` in your `Info.plist` file